# Position of Divs in CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, positioning

[Website I'm building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrQza.png)

Hello, I'm wondering if anyone could help me achieve the layout in this photograph? I'm trying to build this website, and my current progress is being frustrating. I've created the basic layout but it doesn't work correctly.

I'm not sure on how to position the content to match this image. If someone could point me in the write direction that would be great.

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <h3>LOGO</h3>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <hr>
                    <h2>Console</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="form">
                    <form>
                        <div>
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <a href="#forgot">Forgot your password?</a>
                        <button type="submit">Log in</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            <div class="images">
                <a id="firstPostLink" target="_blank">
                    <div class="box" id="firstPostImg">
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a id="secondPostURL" target="_blank">
                    <div class="box"  id="secondPostImg">
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-gvQgAFzTH6trSrAWoH1iPo9Xc96QxSZ3feW6kem+O00=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/feednami-static/js/feednami-client-v1.0.1.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Heres the CSS`body {
        background-color: #13253F;
        color: white;
    }

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

hr {
    border: solid #6cc1d6;
    border-width: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    clear: both;
    margin: 10px 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 160px;
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
}

h3 {
    text-align: center;
}

h2 {
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: -15px;
}

label {
    color: #f0f0f0;
}

.form {
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative
}

.box {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    border:2px solid white;
}
.images {
    position:absolute;
    left:200px;
    height:100%;


}
#firstPostImg {
    position:relative;
    left:1100px;
    top:-300px;

}
#secondPostImg{
    position:relative;
    left:1100px;
    top:-300px;
    padding-bottom:0;
}`
```

Here's the link to the [codepen](http://codepen.io/mortl/pen/zqwOZr)

Comment: You need to post some of the css you are using to try to do the layout

Comment: It's in the Codepen link but I'll add the code too

Comment: Additionally, you need to try as much as you can to make it work. We'll help you with fixing specific pieces, but we aren't going to write you code for you.

Comment: Yes I understand that, I have it mostly working but I just wanted to know of a better way to do it. Perhaps more Responsive then what I currently have.

Comment: I suggest you to use bootstrap. It is efficient way for responsive designs but you need to put some effort and read a couple of articles to understand the grid layout. [getBootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: I'll give Bootstrap another try, I have used it in a previous iteration of this project. I tried to design the columns but they didnt come out the way I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't make it clear what specific issues you're trying to fix. But I do see several things that should be improved in the code. The first of which is the amount of `divs` you have. It seems you may have a lot of unnecessary nesting.

And if one of your goals is to make things more responsive, it's a good idea to use a grid framework (such as [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) or [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/)).

Using Bootstrap, I [created a wireframe](https://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/mnrzm3po/4/) of the beginning of what you're wanting to achieve. I'd recommend looking closely at how the [grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) system works. That'll make a big difference.

[Here's my demo](https://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/mnrzm3po/4/).

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9"> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <!-- Logo here-->
                <img src="http://placehold.it/335x115" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
                <!-- Console -->
                <h2>Console</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form class="row">
            <!-- Form -->
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="control-label">Email Address: </label><br>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                        <label for="password" class="control-label">Password: </label><br>
                        <input type="text" name="password" id="password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <a href="#forgot">Forgot your password?</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log in</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <sidebar class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-6">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/275x290" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-6">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/275x290" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>
    </sidebar>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That's exactly want I need. Yeah I just realized the amount of extra divs.  I was also under the impression that in Bootstrap you need to wrap everything in a Container?

Comment: I wasn't too sure what things you were looking for in specific. As I'm sure you're already aware, the majority of the time people aren't willing to provide the solution for you (like this), unless you have a specific issue/question that you're trying to address. I was just feeling generous this morning, and needing to practice some of my front-end skills! :)

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't expecting an answer for this, but thank you for giving me a solution. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend positioning/styling everything you create. Good thourough code will ensure less issues with different browsers and devices.

Only use the containers (divs) you actually need, give them a class or ID and position everything properly in your CSS. Minimum you should float and give a width to your key structural divs so you get predictable results.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    feednami.load(urlToHT, getHeaderTagPost);
     feednami.load(urlToKX, getKXBlogPost);
});


var firstPostImg = $("#firstPostImg");
var secondPostImg = $("#secondPostImg");
var firstPost = $("#firstPost");
var secondPost = $('#secondPost');

var firstPostURL = $("#firstPostLink");
var urlToImg = "";

var urlToArticle = "";
var urlToHT = 'http://wiki.headertag.com/feed';
var urlToKX = "http://kx.indexexchange.com/feed/";
var secondPostUrl = $("#secondPostURL");

function  getHeaderTagPost(data) {
    if (data.error) {
        console.log(data.error);
    } else {
        var entries = data.feed.entries;

        console.log("Header Tag " + entries);
        urlToImg = removeCharacters(entries[0].image.url);
        urlToArticle = entries[0].link;
       
        firstPostImg.css("background-image","url("+ urlToImg +")");

        console.log(urlToImg);
       // firstPost.attr("src", urlToImg);       
        firstPostURL.attr("href", urlToArticle);
        
    }
}

function getKXBlogPost(data) {
    if (data.error) {
        console.log(data.error);
    } else {
        var entries = data.feed.entries;

        console.log("KX blog: " + entries);
        urlToImg = removeCharacters(entries[0].image.url);
        urlToArticle = entries[0].link;
       
        

        console.log(urlToImg);
        secondPostImg.css("background-image","url("+ urlToImg +")");
   
        secondPostUrl.attr("href", urlToArticle);
       
    }
}

function removeCharacters(string) {
    return string.substring(0, string.indexOf('?'));
}
```

```css
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css);
body {
        background-color: #13253F;
        color: white;
    }
    
    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #00AFE5;
    }
    
    hr {
        border: solid #6cc1d6;
        border-width: 5px;
        clear: both;
        margin: 10px 0;
        height: 0;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
      float: right;
    }
    
    h3.logo {
      margin-top: 110px;
        text-align: center; margin-bottom: 40px;
    }
    
    h2 {

    }
    
    label {
        color: #f0f0f0;
    }
    
    .form {
      margin-top: 100px;
    }
    
    .box {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        background-size: cover;
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
        border:2px solid white;
    }
    .images {
        position:absolute;
        right: 0px; top:0;
        height:100%;
     
        
    }
    #firstPostImg {
        position:relative;
      
    }
    #secondPostImg{
        position:relative;

        padding-bottom:0;
    }

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  form.form {margin-top:30px;}
  #firstPostImg {margin-top: 30px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h3 class="logo">Index Exchange</h3></div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <hr>
      <h2>Console</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <form class="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-7">
            <a href="#forgot">Forgot your password?</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-block" type="submit">Log in</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <a id="firstPostLink" target="_blank"><div class="box" id="firstPostImg"></div></a>
    <a id="secondPostURL" target="_blank"><div class="box" id="secondPostImg"></div></a>
  </div>

</div> <!-- end of .container -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-gvQgAFzTH6trSrAWoH1iPo9Xc96QxSZ3feW6kem+O00=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/feednami-static/js/feednami-client-v1.0.1.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll take a look through your solution.